Can I change my coding in my main in GitHub?
My main is now like this.
folder structure in main
I want to change it to a package structure and located all my files like this.
What I want it to be like
Hence, I've tried it on a branch and everything works.[my folder structure in my branch] https://i.sstatic.net/na6xavPN.jpg I would like to replace it with the main.
Basically I've put all my files in the StoryApp folder, and left only the StoryApp.py(I changed the name to run.py)outside the folder. I've added a routes.py and move all my route coding in run.py into it. Also, I've create a models.py too. Import statements are also changed.
Now, if I push my branch to GitHub and merge , it will definitely has merge conflict due to the different folder structure. How can I do? (My branch that I am going to push is what I want it to be.)
Really need help on it, thanks' a lot

Changing the structure should not cause a merge conflict, as long as there are no other conflicting commits done?
Just do
git add .
git commit -m "Your message"

which will stage all your changes and commit them to main with the specified message.

Handling merge conflicts due to changes in folder structure can be a bit tricky, but it's manageable. you can follow these steps

Push your branch with the updated folder structure to GitHub.
Create a pull request to merge your branch into the main branch.
Resolve conflicts locally by manually adjusting file paths and import statements.
Commit the resolved changes.
Push the merged changes to GitHub.

I hope it hepls . Thank me later
